# how to find out if it is safe to uninstall an application from a production sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dependencies, virtualisation, windows-server

I noticed Microsoft Office components installed in a production SQL Server Box ([which is part of an availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) - currently the principal)

OS is `microsoft windows server 2012 r2 datacentre`,

> Processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz, 2597 Mhz, 4
>   Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

I find installed the `Microsoft Office 2013` -  but the license is not activated.

[image]

I also find the following office applications:

[image]

and when I look at the [windows task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler) I see the following 3 scheduled tasks that are related to the office application.

[image]

I have already [disabled the Telemetry Windows schedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/compat/data-that-the-telemetry-agent-collects-in-office).

I don't believe there will be a problem in uninstalling this office from the production server, still I would like to be clear.

QUESTION:

How can I find out if there are any dependencies from sql server to this application?

P.S.
As it is a virtual machine, VMWARE, I will create an snapshot before I do the uninstall, if any problem I have a safe place to roll back to.

Comment: Any kind of ETL processes? Those might use, say, Excel, for data manipulation. I've worked with an CRM system that required Excel to be installed on the same server that hosted Sql Server.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd just leave it alone. Someone went to the effort to install it, and it is unlikely that was done just to waste time :-)